# How to find all the two digit combinations of the elements in a list in python without using iterators and brute force

Tags: python, python-3.x

If List consists of 1,2 and 3 as elements
 All possible 2 digit combinations are
11 12 13 22 23 21 33 31 32

Comment: ...what is "brute force" in this context?

Comment: [itertools combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: If you have a list of arbitrary length, I fail to see how you're going to solve the problem without using *any* iterator.  Can you define that term in this context?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of brute force...

```
L = [1,2,3]
L3 = [
    (l * 10) + l2
    for l in L
    for l2 in L
]
```

If L were defined as `range(0, 10)` then the maximum total combinations would be only 100, which on modern computers is no big deal. However, if you were considering extending this to more digits, then you might consider using a generator instead.

List comprehension will create a complete list in memory. Whereas the generator is used when you just want to iterate over the results and don't actually ever need all the elements in memory at the same time.

```
L = range(0, 10)
combinations = (
    (l * 100) + (l2 * 10) + l3
    for l in L
    for l2 in L
    for l3 in L
)
```

Notice the only difference here is the brackets.

Running this in ipython would give you something like this:

```
In [29]: combinations                                      
Out[29]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f68103baad0>
```

The generator object can be iterated over, but the items are not calculated until they are being used. The generator can only be consumed once.